# What is the grammatical function of the to-infinitive after this prepositional phrase?

Tags: to-infinitive

> I waited for him **to arrive**.

In this quotation, what is the function of 'to arrive'? I know that to-infinitives are verbs; however, I wish to understand its functionality in this specific sentence. Is it modifying 'him' like an adjective?

As per a [previous question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/297589/is-cry-a-catenative-complement-in-this-example), I also know that a to-infintive can function as a catenative complement; however, I'm not sure if the same applies when prepositional phrases are added to the mix.

Comment: The verb - "wait" doesn't take a infinitive clause as complement. It licenses a Preposition Phras - "for him". The infinitive clause - "to arrive" is a modifier in Noun Phrase structure. The noun phrase is "him to arrive". The preparation phrase is "for + noun phrase".

Comment: Syntactically, ***him to arrive*** is a kind of noun phrase, referring to the "event" of him arriving. Perhaps easier to see if you compare ***I paid for him to drink last night*** and ***I paid for him drinking last night*** (both can be valid ways of saying the same thing). We wouldn't *actually* say ***I waited for him arriving*** (if we wanted a more obviously "nouny" object, it would be ***I waited for his arrival***), but imho it's not inherently ungrammatical (or certainly not *seriously* so).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having found [a resource](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/273747/can-an-infinitive-be-the-object-of-a-preposition) that addresses this question, I am going to provide an answer myself:

'for him' is a prepositional phrase that adverbially modifies the verb 'waited'.

'to arrive' is an infinitive that acts independently from the prepositional phrase. It is a catenative complement of the verb 'waited'.

Answer (score 0):

"Arrive" is a *verb*, not an adjective. Only verbs have a to-infinitive form.

You will often see a 'to infintive' after another verb that is followed by 'for' - in this case "waited" is the other verb.

Comment: I have a question. In the sentence(I wait for him to arrive), what do I wait? Is it him or his arriving?

Comment: @bak1936 his arrival. You are waiting for a person to do an action.

Comment: For clarification, I know that 'arrive' is a verb. However, a to-infinitive can act like an adjective. Here's a good example: 'I wanted a bite to eat.' We could replace 'to eat' with a relative clause: 'I wanted a bite that I could eat.'

Comment: @MJAda that's not a good example, as 'eat' is a verb in both cases.

Comment: Yes, 'eat' is a verb. But the relative clause is functioning like an adjective, and so is the infinitive.

Comment: @MJAda I think you're reading far too much into this "acting as an adjective". An adjective describes something, or adds supplementary information about that thing. "Arriving" isn't a quality that describes a person. It is something they *do*, and once it is done, that's it. You don't forever describe them as "arrived". It adds a bit of information, yes - only because you could be waiting for someone to die, to finish breakfast, to fart, whatever. But none of these things are adjectives.

Comment: I completely agree that it doesn't function as an adjective. I was just confused about how to break it down; that was all I could think of. Anyway, I've found another resource that basically breaks down exactly what I was wanting to know. I'll post it as an answer to my question.